# How to add timer in jmeter script, which we can start at first call, poll the status & stop once the first request is completed & add assertions

Tags: performance, timer, jmeter, load-testing, beanshell

I am doing load testing on generating report and the requirement is like the report should get generated within 10mins.

It includes one HTTP post request for report generation, and then there is a status check call, which keeps on checking the status of the first request. Once the status of first request changes to complete then the report generation is successful.

Basically I want to start the timer at the begining of the first request and stop the timer once the status is complete and need to add assertion if the time is less than 10 mins then test is pass else fail.

I tried multiple approaches like using Transaction controller, and adding all request under it. But this doesn't give sum but the average response time of all the request under it.

Also, I tried beanshell listener, extracting the response time for every request and adding them all...

```js
var responseTime;
props.put("responseTime", sampleResult.getTime());
log.info(" responseTime :::" + props.get("responseTime"));


log.info("time: "+ sampleResult.getTime());
props.put("responseTime", (sampleResult.getTime()+props.get("responseTime")));
log.info("new responseTime :::" + props.get("responseTime"));
```

However, I am not interested in adding the response time of these requests, instead I need to just know what is the time elapsed from when the report is triggered and till it gives status as complete.

All the jmeter timers are adding delays, I dnt wish to add delay instead I need it as a timer.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

[Since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) mainly [due to performance reasons](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-jmeter) so I'll provide one of possible solutions in Grovy

1. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of the HTTP Request which kicks off the report generation and put the following code there:

   ```
    vars.putObject('start', System.currentTimeMillis())
   ```
2. Add [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) after checking the status and put the following code there:

   ```
   def now = System.currentTimeMillis()
   def start = vars.getObject('start')

   def elapsed = now - start

   if (elapsed >= 600000) {
       SampleResult.setSuccessful(false)
       SampleResult.setResponseMessage('Report generation took: ' + (elapsed / 1000 / 60) + ' minutes instead of 10')
   }
   ```

Example setup:

[image]